# Combinatorics Problem - Tiling to cover length $n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, tiling

> Suppose you have $4$ types of tiles: blue dominoes, blue monominoes, red dominoes and red monominoes. Find the generating function for the number of ways of lining up tiles to cover length n such that:
>
> a) no further restriction
>
> b) all blue tiles, if any are before all red tiles.

**My work**. For part a), when I worked it out by actually sketching the possible combinations, I cancelled out the ones that would essentially be the same. For example, if $n=3$ there are three ways in which the board will be all blue which is $3x$ monominoes, and 2 tilings where theres $1x$ monomino and $1x$ domino, however since they all make the board all blue, wouldn't it simplify to being 1 combination? If I do this indefinitely, wouldn't this give me the generating function for the Fibonacci sequence?

For part b), I'm not too sure how to start this.

Comment: We have the generating function of the Fibonacci sequence for one color tiles and no restriction. See my answer below.

Comment: An expanded version of this question, with at least one answer, can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2974255/tilings-problems-with-4-types-of-tiles-on-a-1-times-n-board-combinatorics/2979043#2979043

Answer (score 1):

Hint. In a strip $1\times n$ we  can arrange $0\leq k\leq n/2$ dominoes. Let $x_i\geq 0$ be the number of monominoes, to be put between the $i$-th domino and the next one, for $i=0,\dots,k$. Then
$$x_0+x_1+\dots+x_k=n-2k$$
and, by [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two), the number of the non-negative integer solutions of the above equation is $\binom{n-k}{k}$. The total number of tiles is $k+(n-2k)=n-k$.

**a**) It follows that the number of ways of lining up these blue or red colored tiles and to cover the strip  $1\times n$ is
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n-k}{k}2^{n-k}.$$
The first terms are $1,2,6,16,44,120,328$. Note that here we obtain the Fibonacci numbers if we replace $2$ (the number of colors) with $1$.

**b**) Similarly to a), the number of ways of lining up these colored tiles where all blue tiles, if any, are before all red tiles is
$$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n-k}{k}\cdot ?.$$
where $?$ is a factor to be found.
The first terms are $1,2,5,10,20,38,71$.

Can you find the generating functions now?

P.S. There is a more direct approach to find these generating functions based on "unbreakable" tiles. See the chapter "Generating functions" in  *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.  Another useful reference for g.f. is the wonderful book [*Generatingfunctionology*](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf) by 
Herbert Wilf.

Comment: You are right, the reference should be "Generating functions" in Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik.